# initialize member to NULL in C++

Tags: c++

I need to instantiate a class A without initializing its member B which must be initialized later passing special parameters to its constructor. I am trying to pass a NULL but an error is returned, here is the SSCCE:

```
#include<stdio.h>

class B
{
    private:
        int b;
        int c;
    public:
        B(int b, int c){this->b = b; this->c = c;};
};

class A
{
    private:
        B b;
    public:
        A(): b(NULL)
        {};
};

int main()      //main function declaration
{
    A a = A();
    return 0;       //terminating function
}
```

the returned error is:

```
g++ test.c 
test.c: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
test.c:17:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(NULL)’
   17 |   A(): b(NULL)
      |              ^
test.c:9:3: note: candidate: ‘B::B(int, int)’
    9 |   B(int b, int c){this->b = b; this->c = c;};
      |   ^
test.c:9:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
test.c:3:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr B::B(const B&)’
    3 | class B
      |       ^
test.c:3:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long int’ to ‘const B&’
test.c:3:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr B::B(B&&)’
test.c:3:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long int’ to ‘B&&’
```

Comment: `NULL` has no place in modern C++. Either use `0` if you intend to use an integer or `nullptr` if you intend to use a null pointer. Note that C++ is not Java - objects can't just be made null. Your `B` class will always need two `int`s to be constructed.

Comment: For that to work `b` in class `A` has to be declared as a pointer.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Comment: If the field is truly optional, use `std::optional`. If you're setting it to null because "I promise I'll initialize it later", then reformat your code so as not to require that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You class `A` aggregates a `B`. Each instance of `A` has a `B`, always. It's not meaning to set an `A`'s `B` to `null`.

Want you may want is for the `B` member of an `A` to be default initialized. You can do that by providing a default constructor for `B`:

```
class B
{
private:
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    B():b(0), c(0) {};
    B(int b, int c){this->b = b; this->c = c;};
};
```

Or even just provide default initializer in the class itself:

```
class B
{
private:
    int b=0;
    int c=0;
public:
    B() {};
    B(int b, int c){this->b = b; this->c = c;};
};
```

in both case, you then have, simply:

```
    A(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can compile with c++17 I will recommend using [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), otherwise you can consider having a default constructor for `B`, `B() = default;` or dynamic allocation together with checking for `nullptr`